# Який наголос в слові "тому" в контексті часу: "кілька років то́му" чи "тому́"?

Tags: наголос

У СУМ-11 ["Тому́"](http://sum.in.ua/s/tomu) тлумачиться окрім іншого і в значенні часу, що минув від якоїсь дії. Наприклад:

> Знову затупотіли коні і знову завуркотіли колеса, наче кіт на колінах, але чомусь не так мелодійно, як два дні тому *(Петро Панч, На калиновім мості, 1965, 60)*

Тож наголос на останній склад.

Проте, у схожих фразах:

> Кілька років то́му

Часто наголос чується на першому складі. Це є варіантом літературної норми, діалекту чи неправильної вимови?

Comment: "кілька років по то́му́" - усвідомив, що в цій фразі це слово `той` у відповдній формі в значенні `після того`. Тому змінив приклад на "Кілька років то́му", де використовують і той і той варіанти наголосу.

Answer (score 6):

Слово *тому* — це, насправді, два різних слова:

1. займенник [*то́й*](http://sum.in.ua/s/toj) у давальному/місцевому відмінку;
2. прислівник (а також відприслівниковий сполучник) [*тому́*](http://sum.in.ua/s/tomu);

В українській мові в більшості випадків відмінювання, коли є така можливість, наголос зберігається, і <s>тому</s> внаслідок цього займенник у давальному/місцевому відмінку наголошується *то́му*.

А прислівники не відмінюються, і наголос залишається: *тому́*.

Сусідня відповідь містить посилання на блог проф. Пономарів, який підтверджує цей висновок.

Comment: Для давального відмінку слів «той», «те» **теж словниковий наголос на останньому складі: «тому́»** (див. [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)). Наголос на передостанньому складі у давальному відмінку — це характерний для західних регіонів діалектизм (аналогічно: «мо́я», «тво́я»), що, однак останнім часом набрав значного поширення і, можливо, скоро стане нормою. (Але у _місцевому_ відмінку, на відміну від давального, «той», «те» завжди мають наголос на «о»: і в західних діалектах, і в літературній нормі.)

Comment: Коротко кажучи, я поки що поставлю мінус, бо ця відповідь стверджує частково неправильну інформацію про наголошення займенника «тому» (і підганяє під це занадто теоретичне твердження «в більшості випадків відмінювання, коли є така можливість, наголос зберігається»).

Answer (score 5):

Олександр Пономарів, доктор філологічних наук, [стверджує](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/01/150119_ponomariv_blog42_ko), що правильно говорити *тому́*. На жаль, за цим посиланням пояснення немає.

> В уривку тексту *сім хвилин тому* наголос у займеннику *тому́* стоїть
>   на другому складі.

Є пояснення в статті [Т. К. Молодід. Наголос займенників та слів займенникового походження](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine4-15.pdf), де сказано, що:

> Як субстантивований безприйменниковий займенник на другому складі має
>   наголос і слово *тому́* у фразеологічних зворотах на означення відрізків
>   часу: *п’ять років тому́*, *тиждень тому́*, *кілька хвилин тому́*.

Comment: А от до речі, цікаво, чому слово «тому́» вважається словом займенникового походження. А авторка не пояснює.

Comment: @bytebuster, ось що [знайшлося](http://studopedia.ru/16_46838_utvorennya-prislivnikiv.html) з приводу утворення: "Найбільша кількість прислівни­ків утворилася від прикметників та іменників, значно менше прислівників числівникового, займенникового та дієслівного походження." ... "Група прислівників, що походять від займенників, дуже давня і в сучасній мові майже не поповнюється. Займенникове походження таких прислівників тепер уже не відчувається. Лише знання історії мови може допомогти у з'ясуванні їх утворення." ...